# Delete the row as soon as a column reaches a specific value

Tags: python, postgresql, concurrency, sqlalchemy, locking

If this be my model:

```
class Entity(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    count = Column(Integer, default=0)
```

I want to delete any rows that reach `count` value of 3 (or any number).
How can I do that?
should I implement such deletion in the Controller of my web application and every time `count` is incremented, I check if it's value is 3 or not? How should I care about the concurrent requests that are changing the value? What is the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After sometime pondering and consulting with experts I figured out that solution to this matter is either implementing a lock in database or using redis. Since locking may cause performance problems in multitude requests, It's better to store the value of `count` in a redis database and try updating the `count` value in the object-relational database in specific periods of time.

Answer (score -2):

> Should I implement the deletion in the controller of my web application?

Yes. You should implement it in your controller. Just make sure you have a view that will be able to access your `delete` function in the controller.

> Who [how] can I do that?

Simple. In your controller, create a function that will handle the deletion. The delete function body should look like this:

```
limit = 3 # The value of this variable is arbitrary.
Entity.query.filter(Entity.count == limit).delete()
# The two statements above can be simplified to
# Entity.query.filter(Entity.count == 3).delete()

db.session.commit()
```

Better yet, add a function parameter that will accept a value that will be the maximum value of a column in a row. It could look like this:

```
def delete_entity(limit=3): # I set `limit` to 3 since that is what you have stated earlier in the question
    Entity.query.filter(Entity.count == limit).delete()
    db.session.commit()
```

> Every time count is incremented, I check if the value is 3 or not? What is the best solution?

It depends on what you want your application to do.

Comment: I'm afraid your answer doesn't consider the risk of concurrent requests affecting the `count` value

Comment: What happened if about 1000 reuests are trying to increase the count?

Comment: @AminEtesamian When I answered your question, you did not add the concurrent requests yet.

Comment: @Sean, WTF. Consider ALL requests in web app are CONCURRENT.

Comment: @pylover Thanks for the correction. My bad. I forgot to note that all requests must be considered concurrent. Thanks!